# Timezone display in java

Tags: java, timezone

I need to display timezone in the following format in my UI.

> (GMT -05:00) Eastern Time(US & Canada).

I tried getting the current time and timezone from calendar. But when i tried to get the display name from timezone it just displays as "Eastern time". I am not getting the format mentioned above. Can anyone help.

Following is my code snippet and i am using JDK 1.4.2.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = c.getTimeZone();
String s = tz.getDisplayName();
```

Comment: Can you please highlight the full format string you want? Quote it or use single ticks to make it easier to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the long getDisplayName() method invocation.  Try specifying `TimeZone.LONG` for the style.  The method hasn't changed since Java 1.2

> **getDisplayName**
>
> public final String getDisplayName(boolean daylight,
>                                      int style, Locale locale)
>
> Returns a name of this time zone suitable for presentation to the user in the default locale. If the display name is not available for the locale, then this method returns a string in the normalized custom ID format.
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
>    daylight - if true, return the daylight savings name.
>    style - either LONG or SHORT 
>    locale - the locale in which to supply the display name.
> ```
>
> Returns:
>
> ```
>   the human-readable name of this time zone in the default locale.
> ```

If this isn't sufficient, you can always try **[Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)**.

Comment: I would highly recommend Joda Time anyways.

Comment: FYI: The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). Its creator, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), went on to lead [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) defining the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8+. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you're missing the offset, have a look at the getOffset()-method on TimeZone. That should give you enough information to calculate the offset from GMT.

Comment: i think he was saying it was missing the "(US & Canada)" part.  (simple string + would work)

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Region/City`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
```

Get the standard name of the time zone.

```
String outputStandardName = z.toString() ;
```

> America/New_York

Get the descriptive display name of the zone.

```
String outputDisplayName = z.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE , Locale.US ) ;
```

> Eastern Time

Get the offset-from-UTC (a number of hours-minutes-seconds) currently in use by people in that region. Go through the [`ZoneRules`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html) class.

```
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset( Instant.now() ) ; // Get current offset.
```

> offset.toString(): -05:00

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/dmlRr0).